# Why is font-face not working in Safari, Chrome Mobile, and Safari Mobile

Tags: css, mobile, font-face

I am using font-face generated from font-squirrel. It is working in Firefox Desktop and Chrome Desktop, but not working in Chrome Mobile, Safari Desktop, or Safari Mobile.

I have other sites I use it on and it's fine everywhere. I am using html five blank with a wordpress theme ( as I am on the other sites )

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'futura';
    src:url('fonts/FuturaHandwritten-webfont.eot');
    src:url('fonts/FuturaHandwritten-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/FuturaHandwritten-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/FuturaHandwritten-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/FuturaHandwritten-webfont.svg#font-name') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Please let  me know what else I can provide to help answer this question.

[See the site here](http://kingsizesoundlabs.com/ksl_stage/about/)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console or in the network tab?

Comment: @dowomenfart No errors are showing up in safari.

Comment: Do you have a live site or a fiddle link that we can look at?

Comment: Are you trying to make your whole site that font?

Comment: @dowomenfart pretty much. I'm using a webfont for a few buttons and title. Everything else I'm trying to use that. My mind is just boggled because I use a few font-face fonts on another site and it's fine.

Comment: OK, so what I'm seeing is that you are using another font called Arial Black what you need to do is body{ font-family:'futura', sans-serif; }

Answer (score 0):

I was naming my font 'futura' which was being overidden by the webfont.

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'futura';
    src:url('fonts/FuturaHandwritten-webfont.eot');
    src:url('fonts/FuturaHandwritten-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/FuturaHandwritten-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/FuturaHandwritten-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/FuturaHandwritten-webfont.svg#font-name') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i am having same issue futura on safari is different than on chrome